# Is it possible to test OS in Github Actions workflow?

Tags: operating-system, github-actions, virtualization

I'm writing an OS and would like to create a CI pipeline to check it builds and launches successfully after every commit. Locally I build it using `qemu-system-i386 -d guest_errors -vga std -drive format=raw,file=[FILE_NAME]`.
However it launches in new window and I don't know how to setup auto tests for it. Can you suggest something for it?
Recently I've learned about [this tool](https://testo-lang.ru/en), however I could not launch it in GitHub workflow (I suppose, it's because GitHub actions don't support nested virtualization, however I'm not sure).
I know, I could've use TravisCI or CircleCI for it, but maybe you know any other possibilities or technologies?

Comment: You can set up a self-hosted runner and then run what you want in the runner including virtual machines.